# Visual Studio 2012 not recognizing all pending changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm working in TFS with my team for project and the problem occurs when I'm trying to make new modeling project for my classes, it doesn't show up in pending changes.

So here is how I go:
First I enter my folder where I keep my classes. I've tried from there many combinations: I've tried first right-clicking on my folder and putting "check-out for edit" and then continued to * (see later); next I've tried clicking on .csproj of my classes so I activate my project when I'll be adding modeling project and then moved to *; last I tried to activate whole solution of our whole projects which is connecting them and then to moved to *.

None of it worked. (I was always having last version)

- here is what I did next for all the possibilities:
  I went to Architecture -> New diagram (named diagram and left create new project) -> Create (then windows shows up for creating new project in which folder and I always select my folder where I keep my classes).

After when that was done, I went to check to "pending changes" in Team Explorer, because there should be some available since I created already Modeling project. But there was none. Since I couldn't do it like that, the last solution how I made it was by right-clicking to Source-control Explorer on my project and going to Add items to folder and selected my project which was created locally where I wanted it to be created.

But, this last solution was giving me errors while trying to open my modeling project after. I know I should activate first modeling project, so I clicked to .modelproj and while clicking to it, it was giving me this "notice" or rather "warning":

The solution you have opened is under source control but not currently configured for integrated source control in Visual Studio. Would you like to bind this solution to source control now?

--

What am I doing wrong? Why solutions are not integrated by default while creating my project (my friends are doing it automatically, they don't need to right-click in Source Control Explorer to add item to be able to see pending changes)?

I hope I made myself understandable.

Comment: I'm seeing that any item marked "add" under "pending changes" is not seen when checking in pending changes. They are not in "exclude" either - only "edit" changes are being picked up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like your solution binding is broken. Either click yes on the question to bind your solution to source control, this is information that must be stored in the solution file and while Visual Studio does see that the folder is mapped to source control, it also sees that your solution isn't (did you check the add solution to source control checkbox when you created it?)

Optionally try opening <kbd>file</kbd> -> <kbd>Source Control</kbd> -> (optionally) <kbd>Advanced</kbd> -> <kbd>Manage Source Control</kbd>. You can select project in your solution individually and then click the <kbd>bind</kbd> button on the toolbar to bind them to sourcecontrol manually.

Comment: The problem is that I don't remember if I made bind of solution with my primary folder, but there exists .vspscs which is that binding I think. But when I'm making modeling project, it doesn't ask me if I want to add it in source control. Still, thanks for explanation :)

Comment: I've encountered this issue maybe a few times, under normal circumstances you shouldn't be greeted with this issue. When it's broken, at least there is a UI to fix it. It could have been much worse with crazy powershell scripts or commandline tools :).

Comment: Just had the same issue in VS 2013:  File > Source Control > Advanced > Changed Source Control > makes sure all projects + solution are Binded, otherwise select them and click Bind

Comment: Well done Jesse, 50 answers found none but yours worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and, in my case, the solution was to right click on my project and choose Source Control->Go online. Apparently I must have somehow been switched to the offline mode.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully checked in files from source control explorer instead of solution explorer in this case. Then after that it has worked again

```
VIEW > Other Windows > Source Control Explorer
```

Comment: This solved my problem.  I added the files in source control explorer, and then checked them in.

Answer (score 2):

Other way to do it:
File--> Source Control --> Advance --> Change Source Control.

In the window displayed select all the projects you want to bind to the TFS

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solve it by clicking:
File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Refresh Status

Answer (score 0):

In VS2013+, you can check if your solution is online. In my case, due to VSO service outage, my solutions went offline. I had to open the solution, `File > Source Control > Go Online`.