# Team Foundation 2012 not recognising changes in vb6 app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, vb6

I'm using Team Foundation 2012 to provide source control for a VB6 (yes, I know) project.

On a newly set up machine (installed Team Explorer 2012 and TFS Power Tools 2012), TFS does not seem to be properly noticing the changes. The local Team Explorer says it is connected to the server, and has successfully gotten all the files. However, when I make changes, it still says that I have the latest, and when attempting to check in changes, it says that there are no pending changes. This is despite using "compare" between Workspace and Latest showing clear differences.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775529/visual-studio-2012-not-recognizing-all-pending-changes), however no such "bind" option appears for me in Team Explorer (and adding new projects requires .sln, never mind the fact that I don't want to add any further projects)

Edit: Steps followed

1. Install Visual Basic 6
2. Install Team Explorer 2012
3. Install Team Foundation Power Tools 2012 v2
4. Connect to Team Foundation Server from Team Explorer (inc login etc)
5. Map solution to folders on local machine
6. Make changes to files in said folders (using VB6 IDE, Notepad)
7. Note that TFE/TF Explorer Extension insist there are no pending changes.

Edit 2: It seems all files are set to readonly initally (I've gone back and done it again), and I I specifically check out files, then the edits are tracked. I'm missing a step somewhere.

Comment: Please be more specific, step by step. What steps do you take, and what is the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to specifically check-out files (or use an editor that does it for you like VS), then you should switch to using a local workspace.  In source control explorer dropdown the workspaces dialog and change the settings from Server -> Local.

Comment: Got it, although a clearer guide to where to find this would be good.
I had to go workspace dropdown -> (Where it currently says <PC-NAME>, click, select Workspaces..., select the current workspace, press edit, press advanced, then change the location.

Comment: Local workspace has been the default since 2012. Only pre 2012 workspace default to server.